# Display youtube video using Media Oembed in the node

Tags: media

I have embedded youtube video in an article using [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media)+[media_oembed](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_oembed)+media_internet modules.Media(my field) is a field collection item with two fields - media and caption field.I have custom themed(necessary for my custom bootstrap template) media using theme functions according to file type whether it is an image or video.For image i have used picture module and displayed it as below.This is written in the theme_preprocess_field function.:

```
$row[$field_name][] = field_view_field('field_collection_item', $entity, $field_name,$display = array('label' => 'hidden','type' => 'picture','settings' => array('picture_group' => 'main_story_image','fallback_image_style' => 'w555xh372', 'image_link' => '')), $langcode = NULL
```

When i try to display embedded youtube video using the code below i get an icon and a filename with a link.

```
$row[$field_name][] = field_view_field('field_collection_item', $entity, $field_name, $display = array('type' => 'media_oembed'), $langcode = NULL);
```

How do you find out the correct formatter for the media_oembed module? I got the media_oembed from media_oembed/themes/media_oembed.theme.inc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i got all the default displays in my drupal site using the function : field_info_formatter_types().Since media is a file entity, the formatter should be file rendered.Then i had to give the file view mode in the settings array to show the way i wanted it.I created a custom view mode called article_page(machine name) and added oembed formatter.Here is the final code.

```
$row[$field_name][] = field_view_field('field_collection_item', $entity, $field_name, 
            $display = array('type' => 'file_rendered','settings'=>array('file_view_mode' => 'article_page')), $langcode = NULL);
```